# Error Occurred while executing Soap Test through Command line

Tags: soap, cmd, soapui

Error Occurred when I am executing Soap Test through Command line , it is executing successfully when i am executing it through UI

```
2016-04-28 17:17:49,664 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-04-28 17:17:49,695 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-04-28 17:18:08,589 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-04-28 17:18:08,646 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:129)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:42)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:415)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:372)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the Command Which I am using:
testrunner –c "AddData1" -r "D:\Work\Soap UI\WebserviceQA-soapui-project.xml"

Comment: What is `com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory`? No such thing exists in the standard SoapUI https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/plugins/package-summary.html

Comment: This issue is resolved instead of CMD: testrunner –c "AddData1" -r "D:\Work\Soap UI\WebserviceQA-soapui-project.xml" if i user the CMD:testrunner "D:\Work\Soap UI\WebserviceQA-soapui-project.xml" it works fine for me